# How to use jquery to show value of input range fluently?

Tags: jquery

I have this code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/165/) and below...

but how to use jquery to show value of input range fluently? Now it works but it is not fluently. Thanks for help.

JS:

```
$("#price").change(function () {                    
   var newValue = $('#price').val();
   $("#valuePrice").html(newValue);
    $('#block').css({'margin-left':+newValue});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="filterField">
<label>Price:</label>
<input type="range" name="price" id="price" min="0" max="1000" value="3" />
<div class="rangeValue"><div id="valuePrice">3</div></div>
</div>
<div id="block"></div>
```

Comment: Please add your code...

Comment: my code is on http://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/165/ ... I put it into my question

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/166/

Comment: That's better. Thanks @SaagarEliasJacky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the "input" event:

```
$("#price").on("input", function () {                    
...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use mousemove

```
$("#price").on('change mousemove',function () {                    
   var newValue = $(this).val();
   $("#valuePrice").html(newValue);
    $('#block').css({'margin-left':+newValue});
});
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BaEar/167/)